# How to get the instance by name or type for a closed generic registration with Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following closed generic registrations. How can I get the instance of `IValidate<Order>` registration which is `OrderValidator` if I have the name of the entity as 'Order'.

```
container.Register<IValidate<Customer>, CustomerValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Employee>, EmployeeValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Order>, OrderValidator>();
container.Register<IValidate<Product>, ProductValidator>();

void GetValidator(Container container, string entityName, Entity entity)
{
    // TODO: Get the Validator from container
    validator.Validate(entity);
}
```

Please consider that no more interfaces should be created.

Comment: Note: you can also use [batch-registration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#batch-registration) to simplify registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the actual `Entity` to validate available, you can use its type to build a closed `IValidator<T>` type and use it to resolve the required implementation. Either using reflection or `dynamic` typing (which is a wrapper around reflection) you can invoke this validator with the given entity.

Here's an example:

```
void GetValidator(Container container, string entityName, Entity entity)
{
    Type validatorType = typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(entity.GetType());
    dynamic validator = container.GetInstance(validatorType);
    validator.Validate((dynamic)entity);
}
```